# How output text when decrypting a hex?

Tags: c, encryption

i am trying to decrypt the hex string: 0440 04b4 04d0 04d0 04dc 03a0 047c 04dc 04e8 04d0 04b0 03a4
It should once decrypted properly read hello world!
however i cannot get it to output the text. instead i get a list of integers. does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (int argc, char **argv)

{
    char file_name[25];
    char c; //Variable to hold current character
    int sz; //Length of file therefore size of array
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fw;
    int flag = 1;
    while (flag)
    {
        printf("enter the name of the file you wish to decrypt\n");
        fgets(file_name, sizeof file_name, stdin); //fgets safer than gets, prevents infinite input
        printf("Reading: %s.....\n", file_name); //debug print, can remove

        strtok(file_name, "\n"); //fgets potentially leaves \n on file name, this removes

        fp=fopen(file_name,"rt"); //file is opened
        fw = fopen("revertedfile.txt", "w"); //oens write file

        if( fp == NULL ) //checks if file empty/doesn't exist
        {
            perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //Following code finds length of file by seeking, then resets the file point to the start
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        sz = ftell(fp);
        printf("Length of file is: %i\n",sz); // Debug print, can delete
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);


        int data[sz]; //Init array based on file length
        int i = 0; //Counter set to 0

        while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)  //While haven't reached end of file.
        {
            int ic = (int)c - 200; //minus 200 to the ascii code

            //printf("ASCI Code + 100 = %i\n", ic); //debug print

            //Could do bit shift before adding to array, I Guess
            data[i] = ic; //Add ASCII code to array at i
            data[i] = data[i] >> 2; //Bit shift

            //Debug print, shows what's happening
            int test = data[i];
            printf("%i\n", data[i]);
            fprintf(fw, "%i\n", data[i]);
            //printf("Added %i to the array at point %d\n", test, i);

            i++; //Increment pointer for array
        }
        fclose(fp); //Always close file
        fclose(fw); // closes write file
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the encryption code

```
printf("enter name of the file you wish to encrypt\n");
fgets(file_name, sizeof file_name, stdin); //fgets safer than gets, prevents infinite input
printf("Reading: %s.....\n", file_name); //debug print, can remove

strtok(file_name, "\n"); //fgets potentially leaves \n on file name, this removes

fp = fopen(file_name,"rt"); //file is opened
fw = fopen("output.txt", "w"); //oens write file

if( fp == NULL ) //checks if file empty/doesn't exist
{
    perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//Following code finds length of file by seeking, then resets the file point to the start
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
sz = ftell(fp);
printf("Length of file is: %i\n",sz); // Debug print, can delete
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);


int data[sz]; //Init array based on file length
int i = 0; //Counter set to 0

while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)  //While haven't reached end of file
{

    printf("Current char: %c\n",c); //Debug print

    int ic = (int)c + 200; //Add 200 to the ascii code

    //printf("ASCI Code + 100 = %i\n", ic); //debug print

    //Could do bit shift before adding to array, I Guess
    data[i] = ic; //Add ASCII code to array at i
    data[i] = data[i] << 2; //Bit shift

    //Debug print, shows what's happening
    int test = data[i];
    printf("%04x ", data[i]);
    fprintf(fw, "%04x ", data[i]);
    //printf("Added %i to the array at point %d\n", test, i);

    i++; //Increment pointer for array
}

fclose(fp); //Always close file
fclose(fw); // closes write file


//Debug
int test2 = data[1];
printf("The new file is named output.txt");
```

Comment: i have the encryption code working already just can revers the process for the decryption

Comment: Do you  think `fopen(filename , "w");` can never fail? suppose you don't have write permissions?

Comment: How are you encrypting the code? or was the code encrypted? because it did lack any formatting...

Comment: the encryption code takes a text file containing _hello world!_ and outputs the hex code after it has added 200 to the ascii code and bit shifted right by 2

Comment: You are using %i in your printf.  That's why it is printing integers.  If you want to print characters, you need to use %c.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *decrypt* it, you need to know how it was *encrypted* (well, that still might not be enough).  If you just need to print the character each ASCII code represents, you just need to tell `printf` that by using `%c` instead of `%i`.

Comment: i already have the encryption working the code for that is as follows